# Java - Log displaying a wrong timezone

Tags: java, logging, weblogic12c, atg, oracle-commerce

The log records that are printed in `server.log` file has the correct time and timezone printed as below

```
####<14-ago-2017 18H03' CLST> <Info> <JDBC>
```

But the log records printed in `server.out` file doesn't reflect the CLST timezone data, which is -0300, but still reflecting the daylight saving time of -0400

```
**** Error      lun ago 14 17:03:35 -04:00 2017 1502744855586
```

*Tried to debug with the following steps:*

The deployed web application (ATG commerce) prints different levels of log messages like Debug, Info, Error, etc., through `atg.nucleus.logging.ApplicationLogging` and `atg.nucleus.logging.LogEvent` classes.

And the timestamp used in the above classes are as follows:

```
mTimeStamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

A standalone java class to test the behavior gives the below result, the right time.

```
long millis = System.currentTimeMillis();
Date dat = new Date();
dat.setTime(millis);
System.out.println(dat);

Mon Aug 14 18:03:40 CLST 2017
```

Also the system time of the linux box reflects the right time:

> ~]$ date
>
> Mon Aug 14 18:03:58 CLST 2017

Need help in understanding how and from where the wrong time is picked up by the logs in .out file.

**Additional information**:
The JVM timezone data was updated few months back to reflect the updated data, [tzdata2017b](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tzdata-versions-138805.html)

The `logging.properties` found in **jre/lib** has the following properties

```
handlers= java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler

# To also add the FileHandler, use the following line instead.
#handlers= java.util.logging.FileHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
# setting to limit messages printed to the console.
.level= INFO

# default file output is in user's home directory.
java.util.logging.FileHandler.pattern = %h/java%u.log
java.util.logging.FileHandler.limit = 50000
java.util.logging.FileHandler.count = 1
java.util.logging.FileHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.XMLFormatter

# Limit the message that are printed on the console to INFO and above.
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = INFO
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
```

**The oracle weblogic `/weblogic/12.1.3.0.0/wlserver/server/lib/consoleapp/consolehelp/WEB-INF/classes/logging.properties` has the below properties configured.**

```
#handlers=java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler, java.util.logging.FileHandler
handlers=com.bea.console.utils.ConsoleLogHandler
#java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level=FINEST
#java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter=java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
com.bea.console.utils.ConsoleLogHandler.level=FINEST
com.bea.console.utils.ConsoleLogHandler.formatter=java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.level=INFO


org.apache.commons.beanutils.level=WARNING
org.apache.commons.digester.level=WARNING
org.apache.struts.level=INFO

com.bea.console.utils.MBeanUtils.level = DEBUG
com.bea.console.utils.MasterControlProgram.level = DEBUG
com.bea.console.utils.ConsoleMessagesBackingFile.level = DEBUG
com.bea.console.actions.messages.MessagesAction.level = DEBUG
com.bea.console.actions.BaseConsoleAction.level = DEBUG
com.bea.console.utils.MBeanChangeManager.level = DEBUG
org.apache.struts.level = WARN
org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.scoping.internal.level = ERROR
org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.internal.AdapterManager = FATAL
```

**Software stack:**

- **Application server: Oracle Weblogic v12.1.3.0.0**
- **Java: JDK1.8**
- **ATG: 11.2**

Comment: Not sure if relevant, but… what human language is "ago" and "lun" ?

Comment: es locale, Spanish, agosto (August), lunes (Monday)..

Answer (score 0):

1. check if your OS system is reflecting the DST correctly
2. check if you have updated your java DST using the updater tool, ref: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tzdata-versions-138805.html

Comment: Thanks for your response. The JVM is updated with the update timezone data using the udpater. Also as specified in my question, OS is reflecting the right time and zone.